# LCM with Counter function

Tags: python

ive written a little bit of code to try and calculate the lcm from two numbers.

```
from collections import Counter
from math import floor, sqrt

def primes(n):
    '''Returns the set of primes between 2 and n, inclusive.'''
    primes = {2} | set(range(3, n+1, 2)) #{2, odd numbers up to n}
    for k in range(2, floor(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if k in primes:
            primes.difference_update( range(k**2, n+1, 2*k) )
    return primes

def primes_list(n):
    '''Returns a sorted list of primes between 2 and n, inclusive.'''
    return sorted(primes(n))

def prime_factors(n):
    '''Returns the list of prime factors of n.'''
    factors = []
    iprimes = iter(primes_list(n))
    while n > 1:
        p = next(iprimes)
        while n % p == 0:
            n = n // p
            factors.append(p)
    return factors

def lcm(a: int, b: int) -> int: 
    return Counter(prime_factors(a) + (prime_factors (b)))
```

in the last line of code, I'm trying to display the list of prime factors for both numbers that have the highest count
for example

```
Counter(prime_factors(10))
Out[220]: Counter({2: 1, 5: 1})

Counter(prime_factors(200))
Out[219]: Counter({2: 3, 5: 2})

lcm(200,10)
Out[221]: Counter({2: 3, 5: 2})
```

but instead, there just being added together, so what should I be using instead of +

```
lcm(200,10)
Out[221]: Counter({2: 4, 5: 3})
```

is there a way that I could add the counter before the return part, so that I could instead use the return to calculate the lcm

Comment: Which part of your code would you think is the one responsible for selecting "prime factors for both numbers that have the highest count"?

Comment: You want to count the `prime_factors` of a, and then count the `prime_factors` of b?

Comment: "is there a way that I could add the counter before the return part," I have no idea what "add the counter before the return part" is supposed to mean. Please try to use language more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

> what should I be using instead of +

`|` (union) of Counters:

```
def lcm(a: int, b: int) -> int: 
    return Counter(prime_factors(a)) | Counter(prime_factors(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take max of each factor. So the LCM function should be like

```py
def lcm(a: int, b: int) -> int: 
    c1 = Counter(prime_factors(a))
    c2 = Counter(prime_factors(b))
    for k in c1:
        if k in c2:
            c2[k] = max(c1[k], c2[k])
        else:
            c2[k] = c1[k]
    return c2
```